# Why does my button work in the browser but not on an Android device?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having trouble with getting a button to work on an Android device. When I test the code below in a browser the button works fine, but on Android it doesn't work. And I am also having trouble debugging this as I don't know how to gain access to a browser-like console for an Android app.

**home.menu.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Welcome">
  <ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
    <center>
      <a class="button buttonMenu" ui-sref="myfarmcrop">
        <img class="duh" src="img/crops/mycrop.png" height="55" alt="">
      </a>
     </center>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
apple.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('myfarmcrop', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/myFarmCrop',
    templateUrl: 'templates/farmcropFolder/myFarmcrop.html',
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a ui-sref="main">
      <button>Button Submit</button>
    </a>
```

I tried this piece of code will work. Same issue I was facing earlier. 
This will be helpful for you.

Comment: What is the solution? Using `<button>`? How does this solve the problem where the code does not work on Android?

Comment: Already the issue of adding  a button class to <a> tag with ui-sref is reported with Ionic. So its will create the button separately and uppending the ui-sref.

Comment: Also , You can inspect your device on browser.